# JFXtras Agenda memory consumption

Tags: memory, javafx, skin, jfxtras, consumption

I'm facing some critical memory consumption issues when using JFXtras Agenda. First I thought it's on me, because I've implemented my own Skin which produces variable number of 'columns'. But it's the same problem with the FXSampler application. After 5-10 minutes playing arround, adding appointments, deleting appointments, switching skins, etc.. visualVM tells me a heap size of about 1,2GB (three fourth of it used)

I tried to find a solution but no success so far. What I can say is:
Deleting and adding the appointments is very heavy - when I don't empty my observable list when switching the skins I nearly have no memory problem.
'Somehow' the appointments and some listeners (e.g. appointmentsListChangeListener) still stay active after switching my skins, although they should have been removed.

Maybe any ideas?

Thank you!!

**Update:** 
A heap dump using VisualVM now allowed me to have a look at the class instances.
Unfortunately I still cannot post images, but some examples:

*com.sun.javafx.geom.RectBounds:* 697990 instances

*AppointmentRegularBodyPane:* 9236 instances

*AppoitmentMenu:* 9236 instances

...
so there really seems to be a problem with destroying old objects

Comment: I have just (yesterday) fixed a memory leak; how many skins are in the skin switcher? If there are 2 you do not have the latest snapshot. Could very well be there are more. Switching between skins is relatively new.

Comment: ok, so I will have a look at the new snapshot. Where can I find the main changes? Because I will probably have to apply those to my code 'by hand'.

Comment: well I applied the weak listeners to my code. Maybe some improvement, but still the appointments are the problem: I can switch my skins several times, performance and memory consumption are OK. But as soon as I add or delete an appointment, the heap size massively grows. And I noticed that for each skin-change I made, one appointmentsListChangeListener from AgendaSkinTimeScale24HourAbstract fires. (so when switching 10 times, I get 10 times the same listener event)

Comment: besides, when using the new convertClickInSceneToDateTime method, my dragging doesn't work any more..

Comment: Ok, you have pinpointed a leak, I will look into it when I return from vacation.

Comment: About the convertClickInSceneToDateTime method; that has to do with the right-to-left mode (see Node). The original code in that method used screen based coordinates, but if right-to-left is activated, JavaFX automatically mirrors the nodes. Screen based logic no longer works in that case. So it had was rewritten to use pane based coordinates.

Comment: I've looked into the memory issue and did not find the appointmentsListChangeListener problem. No matter how often I switch skin, there are only two skins firing that method at the same time: one is busy deconstructing and the other one is busy constructing.

Comment: I have found a ListChangeListener problem on selectedAppointments. As a rule of thumb any listeners in a skin to properties on Agenda need to be weak.

Comment: strange, but I got the appointmentsListChangeListener problem in my code working by manually calling the dispose method of the skin after switching. (but without super.dispose() of course)

Comment: .. I didn't really explore that, but I observed that after some hours 'not touching' the computer, the UI didn't work properly any more - so maybe the weak listeners died in the meanwhile !?!

Comment: That is a risk when using weak listeners. You are using the official release or a modified one? Because if a skin uses weak listeners on a control, but the skin is actually used by the control (strong reference), than the weak listeners should not be garbage collected. Of course anonymous inner classes (lambda's) this is somewhat fuzzy. Need to look into how that exactly works.

Comment: This quote in WeakChangeListener seems to tell me that you cannot use it with lambda's "You have to keep a reference to the ChangeListener, that was passed in as long as it is in use, otherwise it will be garbage collected to soon."

Comment: I changed the weak listener code in JFXtras.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed a number of listener memory issues in 8.0-R4

Comment: ok thank you! Beside the weak listeners, I reached big performance/memory improvements by changing the agenda refreshing concept. So instead of always recreating the appointmentPanes and relayouting everything, I'm now reusing the objects as far as possible. I mainly achieved this by passing the currently edited/created appointment into the setupAppointment methods and reacting appropriately. This helped me to decrease the current memory consumption of e.g. a drag and drop action from about 30-40MB to 3-4MB.

Comment: Yeah, I have been wanting to look into that as well. I had a version which used a cache of panes, but I have not committed that. Are you interesting in contributing?